# Amending Radio Station Wordpress Plugin - Show pages

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I'm still new to wordpress so forgive me if this is a simple question.

I'm using the ['Radio Station' plugin] on my wordpress site, however the 'show' pages do not feature a side-bar. I've tried to create a child theme, and amend the coding of the 'single-show.php' page, but I'm not sure whether the basis of the page is either a post or page.

The only thing i've managed to suceed in is adding the side bar which shows right-aligned under the rest of the 'whole page' content.

Ideally, I'd like the ['show'](http://thisisshuffle.co.uk/show/back-to-the-eighties/) type pages to look like the ['post'](http://thisisshuffle.co.uk/shuffle/back-to-the-eighties-podcast/) type pages.

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted six years ago from the date of my reply. We've taken over the plugin from it's original developer. You can find the latest version at https://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-station. We also have a PRO version at https://radiostation.pro. Both free and PRO resolve the issue noted in this post.